# Double precision numbers in a 2-d float

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, double, precision

I have 2 questions: first off.....Im having a problem getting this to work. Its required the numbers entered into my program are double precision. My compiler is telling me that It expects my array to be an int.

The two errors I can't get rid of are in these lines

```
scanf("%lf" ,&array_[rows][column]);
```

and:

```
sum += array_[rows][column]; //formula for calculating sum
```

I changed all my variables to integers and the program worked how it should. I just can't figure out how to make this work as precision double numbers.
Thanks in advance

Here is my full code and program explanation:

```
/*
 ============================================================================
 Name        : 4.c
 Author      : 
 Version     :
 Copyright   : Your copyright notice
 Description : This program creates a 5 row 5 column 2d array.
 The array contains double precision numbers that are then passed to a function
 that adds them, returns the value. It is then displayed to the user
 ============================================================================
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);
    int array_[4][5];
    double rows;
    double column;
    double sum;
    sum=0;

    for(rows=0;rows<4;rows++) //Inputs users double precision numbers to 2d array
    {
        for(column=0;column<5;column++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter the values value for array position row %lf, column %lf\t" ,rows,column);
            scanf("%d" ,&array_[rows][column]);
        }
    }


    for(rows=0;rows<4;rows++) //double for loop calculates sum of 2d array
    {                       // first loop is for rows second for columns
        for(column=0;column<5;column++)
        {
            sum += array_[rows][column]; //formula for calculating sum
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe sum of this 2-D array is %lf /n" ,sum); //displays sum to user

    system("pause");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

2nd question: if you have an array but you want the user to specify how many rows and columns it will be how would you initialize it?

Comment: _"if you have an array but you want the user to specify how many rows and columns it will be how would you initialize it?"_ Declare it after you've read the dimensions (and use a C99-compilant compiler).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get errors because of

```
double rows;
double column;
```

and arrays subscripts must be integers `int` 
so change it to

```
int rows;
int column;
```

about second question  this might be helpfull http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int array_[4][5];
```

to

```
double array_[4][5];
```

Because if you leave int, you are basically saying that you want a 2-d array of **int** instead of **double** and that's why you might get the error. And also as@whd said, change rows and columns into `int`.